# how to pass pass details of item using routes

Tags: reactjs, url, react-router, react-hooks, fetch

I've fetched a tracklist from API and when I click on the track name I have to be redirected to Details page where description of current track is displayed.

This is component where I fetch data and display in the list.

```
const TrackList = () => {
    const url = `http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=chart.gettoptracks&api_key=key=json`
    const [trackList, setTrackList]  = useState([])
    useEffect(() => {
        loadData()
    }, [])

    const loadData = async () => {
            const res = await fetch(url)
            const data = await res.json()
            setTrackList(data.tracks.track)
            console.log(data.tracks.track)
    }
    return (
        <div>
           <Container>
              <h1 className='mb-5 mt-5'>Top TrackList</h1>
             
                {trackList.map(item => {
                    return (
                        
                        <Row className='mt-1' style={{padding: '5px', border: '1px solid #000', display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'flex-start', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                        <Col lg={1} md={1} sm={1}>
                        <a href={item.artist.url}><img src={item.image[1]['#text']} /></a>
                            
                        </Col>
                        <Col lg={11} md={11} sm={11}>
                     
                        <Link to='/:mbid'><h6>{item.artist.name}</h6></Link>
                        <p>"{item.name}"</p>
                        </Col>
                        </Row>
                       
                    )
                })}
          
          </Container>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Here I created Details page where main info has to be displayed :

```
const TrackListDetails = () => {
    console.log('props', this.props.match.mbid)
    return (
        <Container>

        </Container>
        
    )
}
```

But Routes I used in App.js
Am I right ?

```
function App() {

  return (
    <div>
   <Router>
        <NavBar />
        <Route path="/" component={TrackList}/>
        <Route path="/details/:mbid" component={TrackListDetails}/>
    </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: use `this.props.match.params.mbid` instead of `this.props.match.mbid` for accessing the mbid from URL inside your component.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [react router documentation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link/to-object) you can pass state property to link element

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: "/courses",
    state: { description: 'some description' }
  }}
/>
```

You can use it in details page like this:

```
const { state } = useLocation();
const { description } = state;
```

But the problem is that you have to persist description when user reloads page. That's why I recommend fetching track details when details page is mounted.